# Correct XPath query to fetch div inner text

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I am using XPath to query into HTML document where there is following div has text:

```
<div class="h1">2008 Honda Accord Coupe<small> — Wuse II</small></div>
```

I wanted to fetch only the inner text of the `<div class="h1">2008 Honda Accord Coupe` and not include the `<small>inner text</small>`

I am making following XPath query: `//div[@class='h1']` which is definitely returning entire `<div>...</div>` node.

How can I only fetch portion without `<small>...</small>`

thanks

Comment: Unless you do not specify which XML parser you're using this is hard to say. E.g. with SimpleXML you just convert that element to string and it's done. With DOMDocument, you can query the text-node as One Trick Pony has shown. But the correct answer is: It depends on the library / parser you use. You don't say which one, so it is hard to answer because information is missing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `text()` function:

```
//div[@class='h1']/text()
```

Tested in [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5us-ig1)

Answer (score 0):

You can get to it like this:

```
$name = trim($xpath->query('//div[@class="h1"]')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);

var_dump($name);
```