# Getting text from XPath but want elements?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpathnavigator

I am new to XPath so please bear with me. Basic question.

I want to select text, including the elements as well.  Example input below:

```
<node1>   
    <node2>
        <node3>A1</node3>
        <node3>A2</node3>
        <node3>A3</node3>
        <node3>A4</node3>    
    </node2> 
</node1>
```

I wish to copy the content of node 2 including the tags, which is:

```
<node2>
    <node3>A1</node3>
    <node3>A2</node3>
    <node3>A3</node3>
    <node3>A4</node3>    
</node2>
```

However, if I use the XPath `/node1/node2/`, I only get values `A1 A2 A3 A4` (not the `node2` and `node3` tags).

Comment: How about `/node1/node()[not(self::text())]`?

Comment: @Andersson: above expression returns syntax error -  No matching text()

Comment: **Please post the XSLT code you are using.**  Without seeing your code, the best I can guess is that your code is resulting in the correct nodes (elements) being selected, but without specific processing, the default XSLT rule applies -- which is to simply output the text values of selected nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath `/node1/node2` should return a list of `nodes`. Each `node`, depending on what language you are using contains attributes such as `nodeName` or `nodeValue` that you could use to access both the contained text and the name of the tag.

Comment: I am using tibco BW's internal xpath functionality. do you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> However if I use xpath as `/node1/node2` - I only get values `A1 A2 A3 A4` (not the `node2` and `node3` tags).

**Incorrect**.  The XPath, `/node1/node2` selects `node2` ***element*** children of `node1`, not text nodes or strings.  If you are seeing just `A1 A2 A3 A4` for this XPath, then you are evaluating the XPath in a context that automatically converts to string values.

You do not need a new XPath; you need to evaluate the results of the XPath that you already have differently.  For example, if you're using

```
<xsl:value-of select="/node1/node2"/>
```

you should instead be iterating over the nodeset or applying templates to all elements in the nodeset,

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/node1/node2"/>
```

or in XSLT 2.0, returning a sequence,

```
<xsl:sequence select="/node1/node2"/>
```

etc, depending upon exactly what you need to do with the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
./node1/node()
```

or:

```
./node1/node2/../node()
```

When you want the whole HTML node, end the Xpath with /node().

Answer (score 0):

to select node2 elements and everything inside of it use:

> xPath: `//node2/descendant-or-self::*`
>
> css: `node2,node2 *`

to select only inner content without node2 tag by itself:

> xPath: `//node2/descendant::*`
>
> css: `node2 *`

Answer (score -1):

[Correct XPath query to fetch div inner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138441/correct-xpath-query-to-fetch-div-inner-text)

Use the text() function:

```
//node1/node2/text()
```

Comment: it returns nothing with //node1/node2/text() , however returns A1 A2 A3 A4 when I do //node1/node2[text()] - hence issue still not solved.

Comment: @Negarrak, the asker specifically mentioned that they want the elements as well, not just the text.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi He said:"I want to select text, including the elements as well" so, from 

    <node1>   
        <node2>
            <node3>A1</node3>
            <node3>A2</node3>
            <node3>A3</node3>
            <node3>A4</node3>    
        </node2> 
    </node1>

I understood that he wants 

        <node2>
            <node3>A1</node3>
            <node3>A2</node3>
            <node3>A3</node3>
            <node3>A4</node3>    
        </node2> 

the correct expression is 

    //node1/node2[text()]
. My answer is not wrong.

Comment: @Negarrak, your post excludes the predicate indicators `[]`.  The XPath statement `//node1/node2/text()` will select **only** the text, and not the elements.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi there are not such thing, or you are pulling a string, or an array of elements. By they question, he wanted the text. Perhaps he is so newbie that doesn't knows what he wants.